# A problem occurred when configuring project :react-native-reanimated

Tags: android, react-native

I'm running react-native run-android in my react native app, and I'm getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/prikshetsharma/Desktop/Humboi/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build.gradle' line: 89

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/prikshetsharma/Desktop/Humboi/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

How to fix this error?